# Sort article titles in R Markdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have 50+ manuscript titles in R markdown and they are directly copied from a word document. I'm wondering whether there's a function or package I can sort these titles by alphabet order so I can list them back in R markdown.

```
Hospital admission and mortality rates for non-covid diseases in Denmark during covid-19 pandemic: nationwide population based cohort study

Covid-19 deaths in Africa: prospective systematic postmortem surveillance study

Food anaphylaxis in the United Kingdom: analysis of national data, 1998-2018

Association of first trimester prescription opioid use with congenital malformations in the offspring: population based cohort study
```

Comment: Would `sort(myManuscripts)` not work?

Comment: Given they're listed line by line, what's the best way to make the `myManuscripts`? @zx8754

Comment: you will probably need something like `scan`, followed by `sort`.

Comment: Do you have those extra "blank" rows?

Comment: Yes, they come with blank rows when I do copy and paste over the 50 titles. @zx8754

Comment: Try read the file line by line: `myManuscripts <- readLines("myFile.txt")`

Comment: Thanks and it worked - the only hairy issue is that I cannot figure out how to drop those blank rows - tried `na.omit`! But someone just posted a way to overcome it. Many thanks again! @zx8754

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following example, you should be able to copy your text into the `text` argument of `read.table`. `sep` defines that the entries are separated by line breaks, and empty lines are skipped (`blank.lines.skip = T`)

```
df <- read.table(sep = "\n", blank.lines.skip = T, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, 
  text = "Hospital admission and mortality rates for non-covid diseases in Denmark during covid-19 pandemic: nationwide population based cohort study

Covid-19 deaths in Africa: prospective systematic postmortem surveillance study

Food anaphylaxis in the United Kingdom: analysis of national data, 1998-2018

Association of first trimester prescription opioid use with congenital malformations in the offspring: population based cohort study"
)

df <- sort(df$V1)
df

# [1] "Association of first trimester prescription opioid use with congenital malformations in the offspring: population based cohort study"       
# [2] "Covid-19 deaths in Africa: prospective systematic postmortem surveillance study"                                                            
# [3] "Food anaphylaxis in the United Kingdom: analysis of national data, 1998-2018"                                                               
# [4] "Hospital admission and mortality rates for non-covid diseases in Denmark during covid-19 pandemic: nationwide population based cohort study"
```

Comment: Yes, this solution solves the strange blank rows issue once I make them into a dataframe. Many thanks!